# Free online storage to store application settings

Tags: c#, .net, sql, storage

I would like to store my application settings (like user names, passwords, etc) using some online storage or cloud computing
It can be SQL or flat file based
The most important that it will have some free account type

Thanks!

Comment: it's a windows/.Net application

Answer (score 2):

If you're on iOS, look at Apple's forthcoming iCloud which does this.

Cross-platform, have a look at http://www.parse.com/ which is brand new but hosts basic stuff for you, I believe for free.

Comment: no, I am on windows .net

Comment: @Begemotya: it looks like Parse supports a REST API that should work for .Net applications.

Comment: sorry, what is "Parse"?, Thanks